# Calling web service using Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a web service that is defined inside a server by using Java and I have the WSDL of the web service. I used Web Service Client which is provided in Eclipse to generate the stubs and artifacts from the WSDL as how the tutorial in this website: http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html

I have done some research over the Net but I am confused with a few things.

1. How do I actually use the stubs and artifacts generated to call the web service?
2. Do I still need to use Axis or JAX-WS to call the web services?
3. Do I need to involve SOAP in calling the web service or the SOAP envelope as show in the soapUI request?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a web service with java in two ways: **JAX RPC and JSP 109**

I hope you can get detailed information [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-javaclient/).

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can call web service by creating stub and skeleton based on WSDL you have using WSDL2JAVA command. Once stub and skeleton will get created you need to create object of stub in your new service operation(.java class) and once you get the object you will get all child setter methods exposed in WSDL